# SQL Server A network-related or instance-specific error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-connection

I have a windows service that performs a lot of hits to database.  ***Sometimes*** the database connection is down and I got exception "A network-related or instance-specific error".  I got this behavior on two different networks and database servers.  In both cases the windows service and the SQL Server are on two different machines.

Is it a normal behavior that Sql server drop connections when there is a lot of hits?

What are chances?

Comment: I think this question belongs on http://dba.stackexchange.com and would get fast answer on it. Just to answer the question: If the sql server is too busy it may not accept new connections, For Ex. If the CPU usage is very high and is constant on it, then it may respond late to new connection or not respond at all.

Answer (score 0):

Very busy is very relative.

- How busy is very busy? hits/second or minute. When you talk about hits, are those select/update/insert hits?
- Which flavour of SQL 2008 are you using?
- Does your service create a new connection every time before it "hits" the database?
- Do you properly Dispose of the connection afterwards?

If you don't dispose of a connection properly, the connection stays open, which at the end will result in you using up all the connections to the server.

Hope it helps

Comment: Usually more than you can use, that is why I'm saying there must be something wrong with the way that you manage your connections to the server

Answer (score -1):

I was also bothered with this kind of problem, I found plenty of solutions but, still I was unable to get rid out of this, after putting so many effort I got the final solution, I love to share with you all.

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server).

You should do following instruction as mentioned below :-
Start MS SQL SERVER , If there is same problem remain then
Open Run --->  Type services.msc ---> find MS SQL SERVER Running(status) next row which is SQL SERVER(SQLEXPRESS) which is DISABLED or MANUAL in Status set to Automatic then apply afetr start button will appear ----> press the start button, now is the time close the services dialogue window 
Goto --> SQL --> open ---> connected ---> enjoy

Stay Blessed